# How do we render a Custom View to an OpenGL texture. Solutions provided online are useful only to render a WebView, but I want do it for a Custom View

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, android-canvas

I am rendering a Custom View to an OpenGL texture.I have created a surface above a surface texture and am using the canvas returned by surface.lockCanvas to do the drawing inside the CustomView's onDraw method.I am getting an exception near the surfaceTexture.updateTexImage() method.

Below are the errors that are displayed and I have copied my code below that.Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during updateTexImage                             
at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.nativeUpdateTexImage(Native Method)                                                                                 
at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage(SurfaceTexture.java:169)
```

Code: Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GLSurfaceView ourSurface;
    CustomView myView;
    GLCubeRendererEx renderer;

    private final  int TEXTURE_WIDTH=256;
    private final int TEXTURE_HEIGHT =256;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ourSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        myView = new CustomView(this);
        renderer= new  GLCubeRendererEx(getBaseContext());
        ourSurface.setRenderer(renderer);

        setContentView(ourSurface);

        addContentView( myView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT ) );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ourSurface.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ourSurface.onPause();
    }

    public class CustomView extends View {

        public CustomView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setLayoutParams( new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT ) );
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            if(renderer.surface!=null) {
                try {

                    final Canvas surfaceCanvas  = renderer.surface.lockCanvas(null);

                    super.onDraw(surfaceCanvas);
                    surfaceCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

                    Paint ourBlue = new Paint();
                    ourBlue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    Paint ourRed = new Paint();
                    ourRed.setColor(Color.RED);
                    Paint ourGreen = new Paint();
                    ourGreen.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    Paint ourYellow = new Paint();
                    ourYellow.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

                    //Implementing drawCircle
                    surfaceCanvas.drawCircle(800, 800, 50, ourRed);
                    surfaceCanvas.drawCircle(200, 200, 50, ourBlue);
                    surfaceCanvas.drawCircle(400, 400, 50, ourGreen);
                    surfaceCanvas.drawCircle(600, 600, 50, textPaint);



                    renderer.surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(surfaceCanvas);
                }

                catch(Surface.OutOfResourcesException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

GLCubeRendererEx.java- has the code which gives rise to exception

```
public class GLCubeRendererEx implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

    private GLCube cube;
    private Context context;
    private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = null;
    public Surface surface;
    private final  int TEXTURE_WIDTH=256;
    private final int TEXTURE_HEIGHT =256;
    int glSurfaceTex;

    public GLCubeRendererEx(Context context)
    {    
        this.context=context;
        cube = new GLCube();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglconfig) 
    {

        gl.glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);         //Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
        gl.glClearColor(.2f,0f,.8f,1); //COLOR
        gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
          gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);          //Enables Depth Testing
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
    {

        //problematic code
        synchronized ( this ) {

            surfaceTexture.updateTexImage(); // Update texture

        }

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl,0,0,-5,0,0,0,0,2,0);

        long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
        float angle = 0.090f * ((int)time);

        gl.glRotatef(angle,1,0,0);
        gl.glRotatef(angle,0,1,0);
        gl.glRotatef(angle,0,0,1);


        cube.draw(gl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)  //landscape to potrail -changes how everything is setup
    {

        surface = null;
        surfaceTexture = null;
        glSurfaceTex = cube.Engine_CreateSurfaceTexture( gl,TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT );
        if ( glSurfaceTex > 0 ) {
            surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture( glSurfaceTex );
            surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize( TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT );

           surface = new Surface( surfaceTexture );

            if(surface!=null)
                System.out.println("surface isnt null");

        }
        gl.glViewport(0,0,width,height);
        float ratio = (float) width/height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1,25);
    }
}
```

GLCube.java

```
public class GLCube{
    private float vertices[]={

            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, //Vertex 0
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //v1
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  //v2
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   //v3

            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  //...
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,

            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,



    };

    private float rgbaVals[]={

            1,1,0,5f,
            .25f,0,.85f,1,
            0,1,1,1
    };

    private float texture[] = {
            //Mapping coordinates for the vertices
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,


    };

    private FloatBuffer vertBuff,colorBuff;
    /** The buffer holding the texture coordinates */
    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    /** Our texture pointer */
    private int[] textures = new int[1];

    private short[] pIndex = {
            0,1,3, 0,3,2,           //Face front
            4,5,7, 4,7,6,           //Face right
            8,9,11, 8,11,10,        //...
            12,13,15, 12,15,14,
            16,17,19, 16,19,18,
            20,21,23, 20,23,22,
    };


    private ShortBuffer pBuff;

    public GLCube()
    {
        ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);
        bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertBuff = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        vertBuff.put(vertices);
        vertBuff.position(0);

        ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pIndex.length * 2);
        pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        pBuff =pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
        pBuff.put(pIndex);
        pBuff.position(0);

        bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);

    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl)
    {


        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);


        gl.glVertexPointer(3,GL10.GL_FLOAT,0,vertBuff);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);



        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES,pIndex.length,GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, pBuff);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);

    }


    int Engine_CreateSurfaceTexture(GL10 gl, int width, int height )
    {

        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
          if ( textures[0] > 0 ) {

            gl.glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0] );


            gl.glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null );


            GLES20.glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

            GLES20.glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

            GLES20.glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );

            GLES20.glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );

            gl.glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );

        }

        return textures[0];

    }


}
```

Comment: I didnt noticed your Thread that lockCanvas, so your call to unlockCanvas can work.

Comment: I have unlocked the canvas after all the drawing is done in MainActivity.java in the onDraw method above.

Comment: Yes, but where is your lockCanvas

Comment: It's there in MainActivity.java as renderer.surface.lockCanvas